# Jekyll / Liquid: Add item to start of list

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In Jekyll / Liquid, one can add an item to the end of a list by running:

```
{% assign list = list | push: item %}
```

Is there a way to add an item to the start of a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `unshift` filter

```
{% assign list = list | unshift: item %}
```

Comment: thanks very much! Can I ask where you saw this filter listed?

Comment: sure.. Refer https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#filters. Look for `Array Filters` in the table